# MobaXterm startup shell script with input arguments

Tags: bash, ssh, powershell, shell, mobaxterm

I am trying to Run MobaXterm using a powershell script.
On startup, I want it to execute the bash script 'shell.sh' with a '$pathx' input.

this is my function to run Mobaxterm:

```
function moba_open($pathx)
{
    $mobaXterm = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}" + "\Mobatek\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe"
    $command =  "Y:/Public/shell.sh $pathx"
    & $mobaXterm $command
}
```

and this is my bash script 'shell.sh':

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t linux-terminal "cd $1 ;~/bin/lintax *inp ;bash --login"
```

Currently ,

- Moba fails to open the SSH session if $pathx is included in $command
- The shell script by itself runs when executed

I am a beginner when it comes to shell scripting and powershell. It would be very helpful if someone could explain to me the syntax to perform what I intend

Comment: The issue could be `Y:/Public/shell.sh` is not accessible via the "Startup" script if you have it run as an actual startup script versus the /startup folder once the account is signed on. If this is the case, point it to `\\server\share\Public\shell.sh` and ensure that "domain computers" has access to read and execute that script in that path. Usually in a domain environment, "Domain Computers" group is the one to use. If you want to be more explicit, set the folder path via UNC so `ComputerName$` has the read and execute access. The "Y" drive may not be available or mapped at startup script.